# How do I call the click function of an HTML button using the class name of the control or its value but not the ID?

Tags: c#, html, wpf, class, webbrowser-control

I'm creating a WPF application that opens a WebBrowser instance and get the HTML code ...
I was calling the elements by ID for example:

if the HTML is:

```
<input type="text" name="company" id="company" value=""/>
```

the C# code to add value to this element will be:

```
wb.Document.GetElementById("company").SetAttribute("value", String.Format("{0}", Company));
```

where wb is an instance of the WebBrowser Class

or if i have a button and need to click the Click event:

```
<input type="submit" id="button1" />
```

the C# code will be:

```
wb.Document.GetElementById("button1").InvokeMember("click");
```

now I have a problem is that I need to call the click function of a  button that doesn't have an ID but just have a class name and value
   like the one below:

```
<input class="submit" type="submit" value="register"/>
```

how can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `GetElementByTagName("INPUT")` and then find your `HtmlElement` by its `GetAttribute("class")` method to invoke the `click` event.

```
var elems = wb.Document.GetElementByTagName("INPUT");

foreach(HtmlElement elem in elems){
    if(elem.GetAttribute("class") == "submit"){
        elem.InvokeMember("click");
    }
}
```

Comment: will this invoke the c# click event