# Click a tab button on website

Tags: c#, html, webbrowser-control, buttonclick

I want to click tab buttons on website which runs on web browser with code below. I put "step2Tab" and "group1step2" as parameter but getting NullReferenceException error. How can i click these buttons?

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("step2Tab").InvokeMember("click");
```

Here is the html code

```
<a href="javascript:donothing()" onclick="showTab(this,1,'step3')" id="group1step3">Step 3</a>
<a href="javascript:donothing()" onclick="showTab(this,1,'step2')" id="group1step2">Step 2</a>
<a class="currentTab" href="javascript:donothing()" onclick="showTab(this,1,'step1')" id="group1step1">Step 1</a>

<div id="step1Tab" style="display: block;"></div>
<div id="step2Tab" style="display: block;"></div>
<div id="step3Tab" style="display: block;"></div>
```

Comment: try `document.getElementById("step2Tab").click()` - although there is no click event bound to that div so it will probably do nothing

Comment: The event'System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement.Click' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -= @Pete

Comment: Is your question not how to click a button with js?

Comment: Sorry if i misunderstood, i want to click with forms application on c# .NET

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the environment you're working in, you may need to be more specific but looking at other people having this issue ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233151/c-sharp-how-to-click-button-auttomaticly-via-webbrowser), [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12254956/how-do-i-call-the-click-function-of-an-html-button-using-the-class-name-of-the-c)) it appears you need to get elements by tag:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementByTagName("step2Tab");
```

This will return an array of elements with that tag. You will then need to compare by the an attribute of the element:

```
GetAttribute("attribute")
```

I hope this is useful.